# How in Selenium scraping by xpath?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I would like to click the button on page: https://igs.org/network/ by xpath.
[image]
I write example code like this below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
url='https://igs.org/network/'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(4)
myxpath = '/html/body/main/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/button[2]'
el = driver.find_element_by_xpath(myxpath).click()
```

and I have error like this

> NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/main/div/div/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0z5g.png)/div/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0z5g.png)/div[1](https://igs.org/network/)/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0z5g.png)/button[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0z5g.png)"}

What I'm doing wrong?
Does anyone have any ideas for navigating these elements?

Comment: The xpath of that button is `//*[@id="side-controls"]/button[2]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element you are trying to click is inside an iframe. You need to swith to iframe first in order to access the element.

Use `WebDriverWait()` and wait for frame available and switch it and following css selector.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
url='https://igs.org/network/'
driver.get(url
wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[src='/imaps/map.html']")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.toggler'))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

The xpath for that button is this one `//*[@id="side-controls"]/button[2]`

Comment: Your version is relative xpath by my absolute. When it comes to applying it's similar, but both version doesn't work anyway.